# Determine the greatest value of $n$ for which $b > a$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two recursive sequences so that:
$a_{n+1} = a_{n} + 2000$ where $a_{1} = 500$
and
$b_{n+1} = \frac{b_{n}}{1,001}$ where $b_{1} = 50000$

Determine the greatest value of $n$ for which $b > a$.

I have no idea of how to solve this. Perhaps the following is a start?

$a_{n+1} = a_{n} + 2000 \Rightarrow a_n = a_{n+1} - 2000$
$b_{n+1} = \frac{b_{n}}{1,001} \Rightarrow b_{n} = 1,001b_{n+1}$

And then you divide them and try to find a value for $n$ so that the fraction is greater than 1?

Comment: Is the factor $1,001$ that is to say $1001$ or $1.001$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You should find a closed form for both sequences. I can tell you that
$$b_n = 5000 \cdot 1.001^{n-1} \\
a_n = 500 + 2000 \cdot (n-1) = 2000 n - 1500$$
Now you can solve $a_n = b_n$ for $n\in\mathbb R$ (an extension of the sequences). The resulting $n_0$ must then be rounded down for an answer to the question.

Comment: The problem was too easy with 1001. I suppose it is 1.001 instead as you did.

Answer (score 0):

Because $a$ increases and $b$ decreases (by a factor of 1001 each time, which is a lot!), it's quite easy to work it out by hand really quickly rather than finding a closed form for the sequences. Though it might be better to find a closed form if you are intending to generalize for the starting values, one needs to only verify:

$a_{1} = 500$, $a_{2} = 2500$, and $a_{3} = 4500$, while
$b_{1} = 50000$, $b_{2} = \frac{50000}{1001} < 2500$ (because $50000<2500000 <2500*1001$), and $b$ decreases from here while $a$ increases. Thus, $n=1$ is the greatest $n$.

Comment: The problem is too easy with $1001$. I suppose it is $1.001$ instead.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can simply work out a few cases by hand in a table for the answer.

Otherwise, find a simple formula for each term of the two sequences in this way:

Notice that $a_1 = 500, a_2 = 2000 + a_1, a_3 = 2000 + a_2 = 2 \times 2000 + a_1, \cdots$, which tells you that $a_n = 2000(n-1) + 500 = 2000n - 1500$.

Similarly, $b_n = \frac{b_1}{1001^{n-1}}$.

Now $$b_n > a_n \\ \implies \frac{50000}{1001^{n-1}} > 2000n - 1500 \\
\implies \frac{100}{1001^{n-1}} > 5n - 3$$ and so on.

Comment: The problem is too easy with $1001$. I suppose it is $1.001$ instead.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Not to be rude or condescending at all, but the asker's approach to the problem makes me doubt it was intended to be solved in any way apart from simple calculation.